# homeomorphic spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove the following homeomorphism:
$
R_{ \geqslant 0} \times R_{ \geqslant 0} \, \cong \,R_{ \geqslant 0} \times R
$

where R are the real numbers and $
R_{ \geqslant 0}  = \left\{ {x \in R:x \geqslant 0} \right\}
$

If $
\,R_{ \geqslant 0} \, \cong \,\,R
$ it´s done , but I think that this is not true, since it´s obvious that a continuous bijective function $
f:A \subset R \to R
$ must be strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, so considering $ f(0) $ it´s easy to see that a continuous injective function between this two sets cannot be surjective, so there are not homeomorphic, but does not imply necesarly that the product it´s not. What can I do?

Comment: Here's a very similar post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115577/example-of-diffeomorphism
You'll need to modify the solutions offered in the comments slightly, but most of the maps suggested can be extended to the boundary.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a hint: Think of the two given subsets of the plane in polar coordinates.

Comment: Good hint, it´s only sending $
r\left( {\cos u,sen\,u} \right) \to r\left( {\cos 2u,sen\,2u} \right)
$ and it´s easy to check that it´s bijective, the continuity of the map and the inverse map, it´s only because they are restrictions of continuous maps

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Harald Hanche-Olsen's answer is that the map $z\mapsto z^2$ is a homeomorphism from the closed "first quadrant" in the complex plane to the closed upper half-plane.